# Understanding Value Binders

Tags: c++, templates, generics, c++11

Its taken a whole year but I've worked my way through [C++ Templates - The Complete Guide](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/tmplbook.html) by David Vandevoorde and Nicolai M. Josuttis and now I'm stuck on the last section of the last chapter -- value binders, for the past 3 weeks.

The introduction to value binders, section 22.8 on page 457, was simple enough to understand, but I found the examples in the rest of the section difficult to understand. Specifically, I do not understand the *what* the `Binder` (see [functors/binder1.hpp](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/functors/binder1.hpp.html) and [functors/binder2.hpp](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/functors/binder2.hpp.html) and `BinderParams` classes (see [functors/binderparams.hpp](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/functors/binderparams.hpp.html)) are trying to achieve. My difficulty is not with the template syntax but with intent behind these classes.

How is the `Binder` class performing binding? And how is `BinderParams` class identifying(?) parameters? This is  what I'm having difficulty seeing/understanding.

Comment: I have to say, this is a rare question in that every answer I've seen below so far deserves an upvote. they all have a keen insight into your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an implementation of [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application), where you take a function (or functor), and "bind" a value to one of its arguments to get a new functor taking one fewer argument.

This is most often useful for combining *general* functions with *specific* data, without having to write extra boilerplate code yourself.

Consider: you want to transform a collection, by applying a function to each element, resulting in a new collection of the same size. For example, `std::transform` requires an unary function. If you already have a function doing what you want but taking more arguments (eg, Kerrek's `AddTwoThings` when you just want to add the same constant to each element), you can:

- re-write it
- write another function to call the first with one argument fixed
- or, you can *bind* one argument to the fixed value, getting an unary function usable by `std::transform`

---

For some examples showing simple uses of the C++11 standard equivalents of Vandevoorde & Josuttis' system, see the surprisingly detailed [cppreference examples](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: Thanks! It helps with the humility

Answer (score 4):

I don't have the book, nor will I go and buy it to answer this question (which you should rework to be self-contained), but I assume that the general idea is something like this:

```
struct AddTwoThings
{
     int operator()(int a, int b) const { return a + b; }
};

typedef Binder<AddTwoThings, 0, int> AddThingToSomething;
//                           ^  ^^^
//                           |   |
//      argument position? --+   +-- bound type

AddTwoThings add2;
AddThingToSomething add10(add2, 10);
```

Now `add10(n)` is the same as `add2(10, n)`, i.e. `10 + n`.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the signatures of

```
template< class F, class T >
std::binder1st<F> bind1st( const F& f, const T& x );

template< class F, class T >
std::binder2nd<F> bind2nd( const F& f, const T& x );
```

I.e. the functions `bind1st` and `bind2nd` take a function and an argument and return function object's `binder1st` and `binder2nd`. Calling these function objects will call the function `f` with its first or second argument evaluated to `x`.

The section you mention in V&J is an implementation of that functionality. It has been superseded in C++11 by the more general `std::bind` which has signature

```
template< class F, class... Args >
/*unspecified*/ bind( F&& f, Args&&... args );
```

The return type of `std::bind` is something that you can store into an `auto` variable but not mention explicitly. The code to implement is so tricky because you have to store the position, type and value of the parameter that you want to bind.